# How to display an array in smarty?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, smarty

I want to produce an array result like this ['element1','element2','element3'] with smarty. I am working with PHP and smarty. The array is generated from PHP and then outputted by smarty in the above format or style. 
My PHP code is like this:

```
$countries = array('America','Germany','Japan');
```

I want to display the same array content in Smarty but this time the result should be displayed as this in smarty

```
['America','Germany', 'Japan']
```

Could anyone be of help to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [foreach loop](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach) here
**PHP CODE**

```
$countries = array('America','Germany','Japan');
$smarty->assign('countries', $countries);
```

**SMARTY CODE**

```
[
{foreach from=$countries item=country}
    {assign var='total' value=$countries|@count}         {* This stores the total no. of elements in COUNTRIES array in TOTAL variable *}
    {counter assign="count"}                             {* This assigns a counter to COUNT variable *}
    '{$country}'
    {if $count lt $total}
    ,                                                    {* This condition adds ',' after each element of the array until and unless the loop reaches the last element. When the last element reached, this condition won't add ',' *}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
]
```